# How to export and import nifi flow from one HDP to another HDP

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using HDP 2.5 and NiFI-1.1.0.2.1.2.0. Can anyone tell me how to export and import nifi flow from one HDP to another HDP

Answer (score 5):

NiFi can export/import flows via templates. You can save your flow as a template (xml file), and import the template from a file as well. Follow this link

[link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/46683/how-to-save-my-nifi-flow-into-xml.html)